# Calling a member procedure in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

Lets say i have:

```
create type address as object (
   line1 varchar2(50),
   city varchar2(50),
   member procedure insert_address(line1 varchar2, city varchar2)
)
/

create table address_table of address;

create type body address as
   member procedure insert_address(line1 varchar2, city varchar2) is
   begin
       insert into address_table values (line1, city);
       commit;
   end insert_address;
end;
/
```

How do i call `insert_address`?

By doing the following i get `invalid number or types of arguments`

```
begin
   address.insert_address('123 my road','london');
end;
```

i can do this and it works, but seems like a bad idea:

```
declare
  v_address address := new address(null,null);
begin
  v_address.insert_address('123 my road','london');
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: What you do doesn't seem to make much sense. If you don't want your type to behave object-oriented, better create a simple package. It seems to me that you are about to transfer concepts from, say, Java or C# directly to PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have built it (which is bizarrely), the procedure insert_address can only be called in the context of an object of type address, and must be called with parameters line1 and city, with values that have no connection with the object you called it "for".  This is how I would build the table and code, and use it:

```
create table address_table (line1 varchar2(50), city varchar2(50));

create package address_pkg as
   procedure insert_address(p_line1 varchar2, p_city varchar2);
end;
/

create package body address_pkg as
   procedure insert_address(p_line1 varchar2, p_city varchar2) is
   begin
      insert into address_table (line1, city) values (p_line1, p_city);
   end;
end;
/

exec address_pkg.insert_address ('123 my road', 'london');
```

With your funkier model, it seems that the insert_address procedure should insert "the address object itself" into the table.  Something like:

```
create type address as object (
   line1 varchar2(50),
   city varchar2(50),
   member procedure insert_address
)
/

create table address_table of address;

create type body address as
   member procedure insert_address is
   begin
       insert into address_table values (line1, city);
       commit;
   end insert_address;
end;
/
```

Then the insert would be like:

```
declare
  v_address address := new address('123 my road','london');
begin
  v_address.insert_address;
end;
```

Comment: As this is another academic exercise, we have been told we cannot use packages, so i was looking for some other way to do it.

Comment: I think the only purpose of this "object-relational" stuff is to provide material for acedmic exercises!  It just wouldn't make sense to build tables this way in the "real world"! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `static` instead of `member` for your procedure:

```
static procedure insert_address(line1 varchar2, city varchar2)
```

Then you can call it on the object type instead of the instance:

```
address.insert_address('123 my road','london');
```

See [Using PL/SQL Object Types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm#i7523) for more information.